# reducing the size of the selection box around a winforms custom control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a custom control based on the label control.
My question is how do I change the selection box size around this custom control when a user selects it while in design mode.  The need is the box is too large I need to make it smaller.

Also AutoSize set to true will not work in my case, the selection box is still too big.

Comment: Why is it so large?  What is the Text property set to?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a designer based on `ControlDesigner` for your control then use the `DrawFocusRectangle` method in the `OnPaintAdornments` event.

- *ControlDesigner Class - Extends the design mode behavior of a Control* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.aspx.
- *Extending Design-Time Support* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc.aspx
- *ControlDesigner.OnPaintAdornments Method* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.onpaintadornments(VS.80).aspx
- *ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle Method* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawfocusrectangle.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

The selection box in the designer is (and must be) dependent upon the size of your control. If you want to make it smaller, your control must be smaller. There is no way to control its size or position manually.

Comment: The AutoSize property seems to control it some how, this is odd it can't be changed. hum.. how about turning it off, maybe use the a text color change to indicate the user has selected the control.

Comment: @AClark: `AutoSize` controls the size of your control, which is why it controls the size of the selection box.